# How do I debug the “defunct” process causing it's parent to freeze?

Tags: freeze, process, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have program (in red hat) which freezes 1 out of 5 times during its run. Now when I see the `ps -a` or `top` while it is hung, it shows its status as “defunct.”

I want to understand the reason why it’s happening. Any tool which can monitor the process and tell me the cause of it? `htop` can help but its like an hour and I may need a utility which logs all activities of this process.